# Symfony dependency injection

Tags: symfony

I was reading this article about Symfony 3.3 ( yes I am a bit late on this .. )

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default

And the author wrote

> Starting with Symfony 3.3, we added new dependency injection primitives that had the potential to completely replace the cases where injecting the service container was required (e.g. to achieve laziness, or break some circular references).

Wow ! I mean, I can't figure out how new feature likes autowiring, publicness and so on, have the potential to remove the need to inject the services container to make some specific circular references work.

In other terms, before 3.3, when having a service A depending on B, and B sometimes needing to use A implying the need to inject the container in B and call in specific cases `$container->get('A')` how can it be done differently with >=3.3 without injecting the container in B ?

Answer (score 0):

The blog refers to the setter injection that can be used when a dependency is optional. Documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html).